# Image Data URI Upload: Is it more efficient to overwrite an image or first compare to see if it's changed?

Tags: php, image, forms, data-uri

Sorry if my title is a little confusing, was hard to word this in one sentence.

I have two forms on the website I'm working on that ask for personal info (name, address etc.) and a photo of you. The first form is asking for the information for the first time, to add into the database. I have a nearly identical form for editing this info after it has been added to the database. My forms use cropper.js to allow the user to crop their photo when they upload it. This means I'm sending the images from the form to the PHP script in data URI form.

At the server the data URI is saved to file as shown below. Bear in mind that with this script the file should already exist and is being overwritten.

```
try {
    $imgData = str_replace(' ', '+', $_POST['cropped-photo']);
    $imgData = substr($imgData, strpos($imgData, ",") + 1);
    $imgData = base64_decode($imgData);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die("Image data not valid, please try again.");
}

try {
    $filename = md5("SALT" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "." . $_POST['id']) . ".png";
    $file = fopen("../upload/" . $filename, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $imgData);
    fclose($file);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    die("Error while uploading photo, please try again later.");
}
```

Now suppose that when the user submits this form to update their information, they submit exactly the same photo again. When they use this edit form I grab the current photo from the server, convert it back into a data URI and have it in a hidden field in the form, waiting to be overwritten if they chose a new photo to upload instead.

Would it be more efficient to compare the newly submitted photo to the one already saved on the server to see if they are the same, only overwriting if a new photo has been uploaded, or would this just be a lot of extra overhead? I imagine reading the file that's already there, converting to a data URI in PHP and then comparing the two strings, but these strings are very long so that's probably going to take a fair bit of processing power.

Every image will be precisely 350x450 pixels in size, which isn't huge. However, I'm concerned about efficiency as my website is likely to be attacked/abused by certain parties by any means possible.

Comment: "It depends" on the specific throughputs.. I would either not worry about it - as it'll be a rare case, just overwrite it - or use a hash to identify uniqueness if/when such may actually be useful.

Comment: Forgot to add in my question previously, will update it now, but all the images are exactly 350x450 pixels so the file sizes are relatively small.